# Kill View and back to rootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to IOS, sorry in advance if I ask a stupid question.

I use UITabBarController and navigationController to control view.

At my last view, I would like to have a button when the button is pressed, view will return to rootViewController which I set by MainWindow.xib file and kill any process which run in app background.

this is my code in the last view before I want to back to rootViewController:

```
-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{


    JourneyIndexViewController *journeyIndexVC = [[JourneyIndexViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"JourneyIndexViewController" bundle:nil];

    [journeyIndexVC setDistanceLabelValue:self.distanceLabelValue];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:journeyIndexVC animated:YES];
    [journeyIndexVC release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

JourneyIndexViewController is the rootViewController that I set in MainWindow.xib.

Thank you very much for your advance support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You should take a look at this: [UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should pop you back to the Previous View Controller.

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @tonio.mg, I tried it but it just back to the view before.

Comment: So you are like in the third view, and you want to go back to the first one?

Comment: Yes I want to kill anything and back to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a few assumptions here, but if JourneyIndexRootViewController is your rootViewController and is created in IB (in a nib), you do not need to re-crete it when pushing the button.  It sounds like you simply need to remove the UINavigationController that you added on top of the rootViewController.

Comment: Yes you're right. Could you please tell me how and where should I code?  Thank you.

Comment: To do it right, I would probably create a protocol that your JourneyIndexRootViewController implements which is called as a delegate from your last view.  You would implement a simple method in which you remove the UINavigationController view.